# Omit repetition in nginx configuration for subfolders as websites on same domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Debian webserver with a main `/var/www/mymainwebsite` served on the URL `http(s)://mydomain.com`, and many independent web projects also in `/var/www` (`/var/www/mywebsite1`, `/var/www/website2`, etc.) which must be served on the URLs `http(s)://mydomain.com/mywebsite1`, `http(s)://mydomain.com/mywebsite2`, etc.

So the server directive on the vhost for mydomain.com includes many `location` directives for the subwebsites with almost the same `root` directives in it (since [nginx documentation says than when location matches the last part of the alias directive’s value, it is better to use the root directive instead of alias directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)). Some of them include some PHP and rewriting rules, but most not.

It looks like that:

```
server {

    server_name mydomain.com;
    listen 443 quic;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/mymainwebsite;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /mywebsite1 {
        root /var/www/;
    }

    location /mywebsite2 {
        root /var/www/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        rewrite ^/mywebsite2/(.*)\.html$        /mywebsite2/index.php?hash=$1 last;
    }

    location /mywebsite3 {
        root /var/www/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        rewrite ^/mywebsite3/(.*)\.html$        /mywebsite3/index.php?id=$1 last;
    }

    location /mywebsite4 {
        root /var/www/;
    }

    ...

    location /mywebsite19 {
        root /var/www/;
    }

    error_log /var/www/mydomain.log warn;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize and/or avoid repetition in this vhost, since most of the directives are similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I found that several URLs can use a unique regex location directive like the following.

Also, thanks to the remark from [Esa Jokinen](https://serverfault.com/users/274176/esa-jokinen)'s answer, one can use the root directory as he root directive, and put the main website directory in the location / directive.

All in all, the following looks much more short and readable, while still being in the same file, avoiding more `include`:

```
server {

    server_name mydomain.com;
    listen 443 quic;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ ^/(mywebsite1|mywebsite2|...|mywebsite19) {
    }

    location ~ ^/(mywebsite3|mywebsite4|...) {
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
       rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$        /index.php?hash=$1 last;
    }

    location / {
        root /home/www/mymainwebsite;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    error_log /var/www/mydomain.log warn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach to avoid endlessly repeating the same directives is to store them in a separate file and using the [`include`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive to load those whenever they’re needed,  what you’re already using with for example `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;`

In addition [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)  also accepts regular expressions to match more than a single exact string, as does the [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) directive , which, when each or several  /website1-99 locations follow the same pattern can be made  into a single section.

On the other hand, there is lot to be said for simplicity and not overly complicating things. I’d rather have  20 sections than three not immediately obvious regular expression to match sites 1,9,13 that need to have one config, a second  regex for sites 2,3,4,10,11,15,19 that need to be on another and the remainder that needs to be in a third.

Comment: I agree it might be more explicit to keep everything in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use Nginx's configuration to solve a problem that is caused by your own directory structure.

- If the main site was directly on `/var/www`, you would not need to change the `root` directive for all the sites in the subdirectories as it would  already be the same for them all.
- If you insist to have the `/var/www/main`, you could make the root and the root alone redirect to that site.

  ```
  server {
      root /var/www;

      location = / {
          return 301 https://example.com/main/
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Gotcha! Can't put the main website on /home/www (there are CI/CD pipelines and source control managements that need clear separate directory structures) but indeed the domain should redirect to the root, it's much simpler. Then for the root URL, we can do not a redirect because we want to keep the URL, but we can add the following directive: location / { root /home/www/mymainwebsite; }. Stupid me! Thanks for the help. Should you edit your answer for that, or we can post this close one as an another answer?

Comment: Actually there is more to it, I will post a separate answer.